# 'remote_socket' or call Resolve() was not found?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My app has just started failing with the error log below. It's been fine for weeks?

Can anyone help resolve this please?

/index.jsp

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'remote_socket' or call 'Resolve()' was not found.
    at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1495)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.doSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:237)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.access$000(ApiProxyImpl.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:182)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$1.run(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:180)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl.makeSyncCall(ApiProxyImpl.java:68)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:101)
    at com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(ApiProxy.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.apiProxyMakeSyncCall(SocketApiHelper.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.SocketApiHelper.makeSyncCall(SocketApiHelper.java:41)
    at com.google.appengine.api.socket.NameServiceImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(NameServiceImpl.java:60)
    at com.google.apphosting.util.ResolverManager$AppEngineNameservice.lookupAllHostAddr(ResolverManager.java:42)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1353)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1303)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getHostFromNameService(InetAddress.java:659)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getHostName(InetAddress.java:582)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getHostName(InetAddress.java:554)
    at com.nettrekking.Spy.Spy.logRequest(Spy.java:24)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:84)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:249)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:135)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:449)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$CallNotFoundException: The API package 'remote_socket' or call 'Resolve()' was not found.
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:465)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:382)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:786)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:455)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:695)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:333)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:325)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:453)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:828)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.success(RpcStub.java:813)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:904)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:809)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1062)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:908)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:2265)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:2077)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2000(RpcNetChannel.java:147)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:3115)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:602)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:420)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.parseOneMessage(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:773)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.parseMessages(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:651)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport.access$100(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:38)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcClientTcpTransport$1.dataReceived(RpcClientTcpTransport.java:293)
    at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection.handleNetworkReadEvent(SocketConnection.java:843)
    at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection.access$400(SocketConnection.java:40)
    at com.google.net.async3.SocketConnection$NetworkReadHandlerImpl.run(SocketConnection.java:872)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:576)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:878)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:134)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1833)
```